# Launch 2 Projects from same Solution Side by Side in Debug Mode in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I try to do what I describe I get the following error :

"Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Release\AlreadyRunning.exe" to "bin\x86\Release\AlreadyRunning.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\x86\Release\AlreadyRunning.exe' because it is being used by another process."

Which makes sense. I have 2 VStudio open side by side, I launch server App in the left one, and want to launch Client App in the right one. Both are in the same solution and I want to debug them simultaneously.

Of course I could disable or change the build output temporarily for the already Running project in the second VS but I was wondering if there was a smarter way to build/launch only one single project without bothering about the rest (i.e without trying to build the server project, which is already running on the other VS instance).

Comment: Are server+client the same EXE file ? If not, any reason why you don't start both (server + client) from the same VS instance ?

Comment: What types of applications are the two?

Comment: @Yahia : As said below I just wasn't aware of this possibility sorry. Never stumbled upon it until today. Didnt think that was possible

Comment: @Yahia : Plus I want to launch server App before Client App. If I lauch both at the same type I might have sync problems

Comment: You can launch them in any order you wish by manually launching a project (right click) and Debug->New Instance (sorry if that doesn't match, no VS on this machine)...

Comment: @Yahia : I did that and it works indeed (Wouter's proposition) However I am getting mixed up because server calls and client calls are made to same classes and I cant get to know who's calling what. When I have two separate debuggers it's easier to follow

Comment: @Yahia : Please post your last comment as a post so I can upvote it. VEry nice. I am ashamed not to know this feature (I always used upper debug menu, not right click)

Comment: Done - if that is too confusing you can always start the second VS instance and AFTER starting the client attach the debugger of the second VS instance to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VS allows to debug several projects side-by-side... you can start with any project you want (in your case the Server) and when you are ready just go to the project (in youtr case the Client), right-click, Debug->New Instance...

As per comments above:

If that is too confusing (because of several classes being used by both) you can always start a second VS instance and AFTER starting the Client (not via VS but manually) attach the debugger of the second VS instance to it

Answer (score 7):

If you are debugging two different projects you can execute them both trough Solution Properties -> Startup Project and select multiple.

If it's the same project, you can launch one instance trough Visual Studio and the other one by hand (so you don't have to build twice) and attach the debugger manually to the second instance trough Debug -> Attach to process

Comment: Nice... Didn't know about the multiple startup project option. It's always possible to discover new things on VS even after 10 years using it. With the 1st option, both projects will start at the same time, but in my case I need the server to be lanched first so I guess it might not work properly. For the 2nd option, I guess that "by hand" would mean launching the exe file in the debug/release folder and attaching the debugger to the resulting process right ?

Comment: Yeah, by hand means launching it from the debug/release folder.